# Create 1 zip file per file in dir

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zip

To zip a file I use :

```
 zip -r 1.zip 1.graffle
```

This works as expected. But how can I modify zip to zip each document in the current folder where each zip file is a 1:1 mapping. In other words all the files are not added to a single zip file.

Can the following command be amended to achieve this? ":

```
zip -r files.zip .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `zip` once for each file:

```bsh
for f in *.graffle; do zip -r "${f%%.*}.zip" "$f"; done
```

This will run over all `.graffle` files and call `zip` on each of them. The archive name will be set based on the filename, minus the `.graffle` extension, which is removed via [string manipulation](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

If you want to zip files of multiple extensions, simply add them to the beginning, e.g. `for f in *.graffle *.jpg` and so on.

Note that this might be kind of slow, since it will process one file at a time. If you have [GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) (which you can install via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) using `brew install parallel`):

```bsh
parallel 'zip -r {.}.zip {}' ::: *.graffle
```

This will run all the ZIP commands in parallel, using multiple cores, so it will be much faster if you have a lot of files. Here, `{.}` takes care of removing the extension from the input file name, and `{}` is replaced with the file name itself.

Answer (score -1):

If you are in the same directory that contains the files, you can execute:

```
$ for f in $(ls -1); do zip -r $f.zip $f; done;
```

Or in another directory:

```
for f in $(ls -1 /path/to/files); do zip -r $f.zip $f; done;
```

Comment: Note that this works precisely once -- after that, it would zip the .zip files into .zip.zip files.

Comment: In addition to the problem with zipping the zip files, please do not parse `ls` output. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs – doing so is very unsafe, and your script will already break if any file name has a space in it.